# How to do raw queries in Laravel Jenssegers Mongodb ORM?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel with jessenger mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb), and I have the following object collections in mongodb:

User: (id,name,email)

and

Message (from_id,to_id,text)

I need to run the following query over the two collections:

```
db.User.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Message",
         localField: "id",
         foreignField: "from_id",
         as: "user_message"
       }
  }
  ,{$match:{id:1}}
])
```

What I am wondering is how to do this in jesenger laravel (ORM/Object-oriented style)... Normally I would do `Message::where('from_id', '=', $user->_id)->get(['to_id'])` .... etc... but how do I run or translate the above query? thanks.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `embedsMany`. `$this->embedsMany('message', 'from_id')` If you define that as the `messages` function on the `User` model you should be able to do `$user->messages`

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is the equivalent of a relational join: (SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Messages ON Users.id=Messages.from_id WHERE to_id='xxxx') ... I need to get the user objects corresponding to the from_id.  I could run two queries (first get all the ids, then get all the users for those ids), but the problem is that I need to use orderBy, limit and offset, which means it must be done in one query... (as i cannot limit the first query before the second, as the ordering,limit etc... needs to happen after they are merged...)

Comment: Is there a reason that `embedsMany` won't work for you?

Comment: I am not fully sure I understand what you mean, could you maybe post as an answer with code example?  that would be very helpful :) In advance, thanks a lot...

Comment: Added what I'm talking about as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your users model you can define the relationship to messages using `embedsMany`:

```
/**
 * messages that were received by the user
 */
public function messagesSent() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'from_id');
}


/**
 * Messages that were sent to the user
 */
public function messagesReceived() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'to_id');
}
```

You will also want to have the relationships on the `messages` model to indicate who the `sender/receiver` were, so that you can eager load those:

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from_id');
}
```

You may as well define the receiver as well:

```
public function receiver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::clas, 'to_id');
}
```

Now if you want, say, latest messages from top to bottom, don't use the `User` model to define this, start with the `Message` model so you're not stuck trying to order by a relationship, when it's easier in your case not to:

```
Message::with(['sender'])
    ->where('from_id', $user->id)
    ->limit(20)
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->take(50);
```

If you just want all messages for the user with their `senders` relationship loaded:

```
User::with(['messagesReceived', 'messagesReceived.sender'])
    ->where('id', $user_id)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: How would i go about getting the sender of each message?  Could i then add an embedsMany function in Message.php as sender(){...} and go $user->messages()-sender()->orderBy .... to get all senders? thanks

Comment: @DanielValland No, you would need to work backwards `sender->mesages->user` And no worries, I've never worked with MongoDB in Laravel personally, but the documentation made sense.

Comment: What I mean is, suppose I have a given user, I then want to fetch a list of all users that have sent a message to this user... I would then have a $users->messages() which would return all messages received by the user, I then want to fetch the senders of ALL these messages, so I would want something like $user->messages()->senders() ... but not sure how to do that...

Comment: @DanielValland I've updated my answer to better reflect what I think it is you're after